# element.styleの値を取得できない

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

WordPressで作成しているサイトに、jQuery/JavaScriptでcssのleft、top、transform:scaleを操作するかたちで、画像を左右、拡大縮小できる機能をつくりました。
さらに、上記の値を取得したいのですが、値は「element.style」に反映されており、取得がうまくいきません。
この「element.style」の値を取得する方法を教えていただけますでしょうか？

[image: エラー]

[image: コード]

[image: css]

追記
アドバイス頂いた通り、下記２パターン試してみましたが、両方エラーが出てしまいます。
何が問題なのかご指摘いただけますと有り難いです。

```
$(function(){
$("#ss").on("click", function(){
        //var img_css = document.querySelector("#preveiw_card_image_inner img").style;
        var img_css = $("#preveiw_card_image_inner img");
        var cssvalue = getComputedStyle(img_css[0], "");
        //alert(img_css);
        alert(cssvalue);
    });
});
```

Comment: コードは画像ではなくテキストで質問文に挿入してください。

Comment: すみません、今後そのようにいたします。ご指摘いただきありがとうございます。

Comment: 「下記2パターン」ではどんなエラーが出ましたか?

Answer (score 1):

`img_css` は jQuery オブジェクトで、`getComputedStyle()` には Element を指定する必要があります。

```
var cssvalue = getComputedStyle(img_css[0], "");
```

jQueryを使うとこういうトラブルや覚えないといけないことが増えるので、個人的には初心者はjQueryを使うべきではないと思ってます。

この場合、`getComputedStyle()`を使わずに、Elementオブジェクトの`style`プロパティにアクセスすることも可能です。

```js
document.querySelector('#preview_card_image_inner img').style
```